# Add Another Card to the Right PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

How can i add another user to its right, when i limit it to 5 it goes down not to the right im pretty stuck here how can i align it, i dont know the term or what you call that thing thanks in advance

```
<h2>Recently Added</h2>
      <?php
  include_once('connection.php');


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstdpro

ORDER BY StdID DESC LIMIT 0, 5";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $count = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       $StudentID="<a href='ProfileRecords.php?id=".$row['StdID']."'>".$row['StdID']."</a>";
   $StdName="<a href='ProfileRecords.php?id=".$row['StdID']."'>" . $row['Fname'] . ' ' . $row['Lname'] . "</a>";

  ?>
      <div class="col-md-6">
                  <!-- USERS LIST -->
                  <div class="box box-danger">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                      <h3 class="box-title">Latest Members</h3>
                      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <span class="label label-danger"> New Members</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body no-padding">
                      <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                        <li>
                          <img src="<?php echo $row['StdImage'];?>" alt="User Image">
                          <a class="users-list-name" href="#"><?php echo "$StdName" ?></a>
                          <span class="users-list-date"><?php echo "$StudentID" ?></span>
                          <?php } ?>

                    <div class="box-footer text-center">
                      <a href="javascript::" class="uppercase">View All Users</a>
                    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
                  </div><!--/.box -->
                </div><!-- /.col -->
              </div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue, not PHP/SQL. Whats the generated source and the CSS?

Comment: i used bootstrap